# how to draw an image with PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom

Tags: c#

In my application I need to print employee photo as ID Badge .I have used picture box control and sizemode as PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage.
When printing this, the photo gets wider according to the Picture box Width and Height. But the photo doesn’t look like as an original one.
Its perfect when I set sizemode as PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom in designer window. But while printing, the result will be same as before. There is no effect.

```
PictureBox pict = (PictureBox)ctrl;
pict.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(pict.Location.X, pict.Location.Y, pict.Width, pict.Height);
e.Graphics.DrawImage(pict.Image, rect);
```

The above code will execute when the  PrintPage event is Triggered

Comment: SizeMode does *not* affect the image at all, only the Graphics.DrawImage() call that PictureBox uses to paint the image.  Which you will have to reproduce in your own code.  Otherwise simple to do by using Graphics.ScaleTransform()

Answer (score 1):

I think before clicking on the print button, you can try capturing the bitmap of your `PictureBox` in `Zoom` mode like this:

```
PictureBox pict = (PictureBox)ctrl;
pict.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
var bm = new Bitmap(pict.ClientSize.Width, pict.ClientSize.Height);
pict.DrawToBitmap(bm, pict.ClientRectangle);
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, pict.Bounds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//The Rectangle (corresponds to the PictureBox.ClientRectangle)
//we use here is the Form.ClientRectangle
//Here is the Paint event handler of your Form1
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e){
  ZoomDrawImage(e.Graphics, yourImage, ClientRectangle);
}
//use this method to draw the image like as the zooming feature of PictureBox
private void ZoomDrawImage(Graphics g, Image img, Rectangle bounds){
  decimal r1 = (decimal) img.Width/img.Height;
  decimal r2 = (decimal) bounds.Width/bounds.Height;
  int w = bounds.Width;
  int h = bounds.Height;
  if(r1 > r2){
    w = bounds.Width;
    h = (int) (w / r1);
  } else if(r1 < r2){
    h = bounds.Height;
    w = (int) (r1 * h);
  }
  int x = (bounds.Width - w)/2;
  int y = (bounds.Height - h)/2;
  g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(x,y,w,h));
}
```

To test it on your form perfectly, you should also have to set ResizeRedraw = true and enable DoubleBuffered:

```
public Form1(){
  InitializeComponent();
  ResizeRedraw = true;
  DoubleBuffered = true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I've realized that this code looks very same to the code I posted before (not long) in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101882/picturebox-zoom-mode-effect-with-graphics-object/20107316#20107316 ?

Comment: @King - it violates the license terms of this web site.  You probably need to explain that.  Requirements are a link to the original post as well as a link to the profile of the author of that post.